# How to boot Solaris from network (using Windows 7)

Tags: windows, networking, boot, solaris

Currently I have a single Board Computer: Themis USPIIe-USB™ 6U VMEbus computer board based on the Sun® Microsystems 550-MHz and 650-MHz 64-bit UltraSPARC® processors.  Currently it boots from an attached Hard Disk which I need to get rid of. The Themis card is connected to a network and the network and I have another system running Windows 7. How can I network boot the Themis card (Sparc/Solaris) from Windows 7?